# How to convert Spark R dataframe into R list

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, rstudio, sparkr

This is my first time to try Spark R to do the same work I did with RStudio, on Databricks Cloud Community Edition. But met some weird problems.

It seems that Spark R do support packages like ggplot2, plyr, but the data has to be in R list format. I could generate this type of list in R Studio when I am using `train <- read.csv("R_basics_train.csv")`, variable `train` here is a list when you use `typeof(train)`.

However, in Spark R, when I am reading the same csv data as "train", it will be converted into dataframe, and this is not the Spark Python DataFrame we have used before, since I cannot use `collect()` function to convert it into list.... When you use `typeof(train)`, it shows the type is `"S4"`, but in fact the type is dataframe....

So, is there anyway in Spark R that I can convert dataframe into R list so that I can use methods in ggplot2, plyr?

You can find the origional .csv training data here:
[train](https://github.com/hanhanwu/Hanhan_Data_Science_Practice/blob/master/R_basics_train.csv)

Comment: can you show us what is `dput(train)`?

Comment: I put the .csv training data in my GitHub here: https://github.com/hanhanwu/Hanhan_Data_Science_Practice/blob/master/R_basics_train.csv

Comment: or do `dput(head(train))` if train is large and if `head` works on it

Comment: head is not a good choice for data exploration. When using R Studio, it is quite easy to tell where are the missing data, and detailed summary of each column. But I didn't find Spark R could do these. head() cannot help either...

Comment: `dput(head(train))` may be good here. I know some about S4 objects but I need an example to work with before I can show you how to convert.

Comment: I just tried `dput(head(train))` on Spark cloud, it just converts the results in to a list and I still could not get the summary as R Studio could give..... If you want the example, the origional training data (.csv) is here: https://github.com/hanhanwu/Hanhan_Data_Science_Practice/blob/master/R_basics_train.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later I found that using `r_df <- collect(spark_df)` will convert Spark DataFrame into R dataframe, although cannot use R summary() on its dataframe, with R dataframe, we can do many R operations.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they changed SparkR, so you now need to use

```
r_df<-as.data.frame(spark_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you call this as the drawback of sparkR, but in order to leverage many good functionalities which R has to offer such as data exploration, ggplot libraries, you need to convert your pyspark data frame into normal data frame by calling collect

```
df <- collect(df)
```